# Excel Formula for looping and if statement

Tags: excel-formula

we are using excel to run a customer journey where we would like to find out after the first call what is the reason for calling.

So if for example cust ABC called regarding Billing query on the first call and the second call is Technical query. Does anyone knows if there is a formula in excel which uses the logic "for all first calls give me the reason for the second call"

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. It's way easier for everyone to help you if you include a screenshot of your sheet, As of now it's hard to figure out what you need.

Comment: Is you data sorted by **date** ??

Comment: yes it is sorted by date